# How do I conditional format based on an increase in % from the cell directly to the left, and apply to the entire dataset (in Microsoft excel)?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Using Microsoft Excel, I would like to use conditional formatting to highlight trends within a large database. The dataset contains 2000+ rows of data set out like this:

| Country | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| South Africa | 10300.21 | 12423.04 | 12302.29 | 29193.20 |
| Sri Lanka | 10140.48 | 15426.09 | 12242.67 | 14693.43 |

I would like to use conditional formatting within Excel to highlight cells for which the value is 20% larger (green) than the cell directly to the left. I would also like to highlight cells (red) for which the value is 20% lower to the cell directly to the left. I would like to use this formatting for the entire dataset, but ideally a quick way which means not performing the formatting row-by-row.

If this isn't possible using Excel, I would appreciate any advice for performing this using R.

Thanks for your help!

[I tried performing this using Excel but struggled find ways to to duplicate this row-by-row without using the conditional formatting tool on every row individually.]

Answer (score 2):

Apply to range: `=$C$2:$E$3`

Rule for green: `=C2>B2*1.2`

Rule for red: `=C2<B2*0.8`

Result:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted your answer. Just a clarification: what if the difference is exactly 20%? No highlight?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns: I believe you can easily replace "<" and ">" in the formulae by "<=" and ">=".

Comment: That "apply to range" is quite interesting: up to now I was always copying the format, which is not a good way to do this.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns for "20% and more ">=" and "<=" should be used, for "more than 20%" ">" and "<" should be used, for "exact 20% greater" or "exact 20% lower" "=" should be used. For me it wasn't completely clear what is the case

Comment: @Dominique what do you mean by "copying the format"?

Comment: @user11222393: I mean the paintbrush in the "clipboard" menu in the main ribbon.

Comment: I have never used it before! Looks like a fast way to make corrections, but only on small ranges